# External function Java

Tags: java

I have imported the class from my jar file with import enji.lep.Msg;

In my new class (Chat) I want to use a "public void" function from the Msg class imported.
the Msg.class haz this public void in it:

```
public void logEnable(String pName, String pVer) {
    logThis(Msg.oeli + pName + " Edition " + pVer + " enabled.");
}
```

And in my Chat.class I imported the class which contains logEnable() but I can't do

```
logEnable(pName, pVer);
```

Am I doing it wrong? How should I do? :/

Comment: You are not using the Msg class instance in calling the logEnable in the chat class.

Answer (score 2):

This "functions" are actually methods of classes Msg, Chat etc. To call method of class you have to create instance first, i.e. do something like this:

```
Msg m = new Msg();
m.logEnable("foo", "bar");
```

Comment: Oh awesome! I was just goign to ask the guy below how to make it with that "= new" thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
new Msg().logEnable(pName, pVer);
```

You need to denote the object you want to call a method on. Here, we are creating a throwaway object. You could also save it to a variable:

```
Msg msg = new Msg();
msg.logEnable(pName, pVer);
```

If you just do `logEnable(pName, pVer)`, the compiler will treat this as `this.logEnable(pName, pVer)`, that is, it automatically inserts an object (`this`) for you.

This is all really basic stuff. I think you need to go through a tutorial first. This looks like homework to me. Have fun learning to program! We all started out with questions like yours ;)